# Show Perf Monitor in developer menu, is not showing ram information

Tags: react-native, debugging

My react native app not showing RAM information as i see [in react native profiling documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#profiling):

**How is it in my app:**

[image: my app informations]

**Expected:**

[image: Doc informations]

Could someone help me?